# No Images Displaying running on iPad but are in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xcode4

so in a very tired/end of work day state I was changing some of the target settings in my build to overcome an issue that sprung up with provisioning profiles, I successfully got the app to run on a new device.  Problem being none of the images show up in the app?  The issue was not happening before I changed some of the app target settings so I know its not the normal answer I see around here of checking the images names for capitalization inconsistencies.
The app runs fine in the simulator and did 30 minutes prior on my device but now there is blank space where the images used to be while running on my device.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?  I will gladly provide anymore information to help better everyones assistance effors, im just not sure what other information would be valuable in tracking down the cause.

Thanks a ton for everyone who helps, this is really frustrating.

**Edit**
WHile all the images are included in the copy bundle resources section, they are not appearing in the app bundle upon running to the device (as checked in iExplorer).  Upon manually moving the images into the app bundle on my device in iExplorer they load in the app.
Does anyone know why they are not actually copying over?

Answer (score 2):

If you were changing the target settings of your application, are you sure that your images are making it into the build for device?  Check the Build Phases tab of your target and make sure that your images are showing up in the Copy Bundle Resources phase.

Comment: I just opened up the .app through iExplorer and it appears that no images are being copied over even though it shows them in the Copy Bundle resources.  Can you think of any cause for that?

Answer (score 1):

Check the Targets-->Build Phases-->Copy bundle Resources

[image]

Comment: thanks Meet but check one answer below, " 
I just opened up the .app through iExplorer and it appears that no images are being copied over even though it shows them in the Copy Bundle resources. Can you think of any cause for that? – JLoewy 9 mins ago "

Comment: Try to re-add the images in copy bundle resource. It had worked for me.

Comment: Thats not the case either, i tried both removing and readding and adding new images entirely and nothing is getting copied over to app bundle

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have tried it after cleaning the build from device or simulator and from xcode. It's a general problem sometimes.

Comment: I performed a "clean" through xcode, is their any other method I should try?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem when the image filename starts with a capital letter. Make sure all of your image names start with lowercase.

Comment: tried images starting wtih lowercase images and to no avail, sorry thanks for the attempt though